# In Flutter, I want to use the old Material 2 RawChip oval style

Tags: flutter, material3

I'd like to use Material 3 for my project, but I like the old RawChip Oval look.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the widget with [`Theme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) and give it a `ThemeData` with `useMaterial3` set to `false`.

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
  child: RawChip(...)
)
```